# Photoshop Script Returning Error 8800 when exporting video

Tags: javascript, typescript, photoshop, psd

I am having an issue with exporting video on photoshop as .mp4 and its throwing this error after trying to save.

[image]

I don't see an Issue anywhere on my code as to why it would be giving me this error. Here is my code the export and input folder paths are the same. it seems to grab the png files from the input folder fine.

```
var inputF = Folder('D:/START/');
var sav = Folder('D:/START/');
var alpha = 'F';

if (app.documents.length) {
var doc = activeDocument;
doc.activeLayer = doc.layers.getByName("Design");
var al = doc.activeLayer;
if (al.kind == LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT) {
    if (inputF.exists) {
        var img = inputF.getFiles(/\.(png|jpg)$/i);
        if (img.length > 0) {
            if (sav.exists) {
                for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
                    var imgF = img[i];
                    var imgNm = imgF.displayName.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
                    if (imgNm[imgNm.length - 1] == 'C') {
                        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);
                        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);
                        var layers = activeDocument.layers;
                        if (layers) {
                            activeDocument.activeLayer = layers[0];
                            replaceeWithImage(imgF);
                            activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
                            activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
                            savVideo(sav, imgNm + '-' + alpha + '.mp4');

                        } else {
                            activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
                            alert("No Smart Object Layer Found Inside The Smart Object Layer");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert("Images processed successfully!");
                $.sleep(4000);
                doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    alert("Select The Smart Object Layer Befor Running the script", "Smart Object Layer")
}
} else {
alert("Open a Template First", "Template")
}

function savVideo(outPath, fileName) {
var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
desc2.putPath(stringIDToTypeID("directory"), new File(outPath));
desc2.putString(charIDToTypeID('Nm  '), fileName);
desc2.putString(stringIDToTypeID("ameFormatName"), "H.264");
desc2.putString(stringIDToTypeID("amePresetName"), "2_Medium Quality.epr");
desc2.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("useDocumentSize"), true);
desc2.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("useDocumentFrameRate"), true);
desc2.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("pixelAspectRatio"), stringIDToTypeID("pixelAspectRatio"), charIDToTypeID('Dcmn'));
desc2.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("fieldOrder"), stringIDToTypeID("videoField"), stringIDToTypeID("preset"));
desc2.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("manage"), true);
desc2.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("allFrames"), true);
desc2.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("renderAlpha"), stringIDToTypeID("alphaRendering"), charIDToTypeID('None'));
desc2.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('Qlty'), 1);
desc2.putInteger(stringIDToTypeID("Z3DPrefHighQualityErrorThreshold"), 5);
desc1.putObject(charIDToTypeID('Usng'), stringIDToTypeID("videoExport"), desc2);
executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Expr'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
};

function replaceeWithImage(filePath) {
try {
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putPath(charIDToTypeID('null'), new File(filePath));
    executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerReplaceContents'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
};
```

**PSD FILE I AM USING:**
removed

**EDIT HERE IS THE WORKING CODE:**

```
var inputF = Folder('D:/START/');
var sav =  Folder('D:/START/');
var alpha = '-B';
if (app.documents.length) {
var doc = activeDocument;
doc.activeLayer = doc.layers.getByName("Design");
var docH=doc.height.as('px');
if(docH>2304)doc.resizeImage (null, UnitValue(docH,'px'), doc.resolution, ResampleMethod.AUTOMATIC);
var al = doc.activeLayer;
if (al.kind == LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT) {
    if (inputF.exists) {
        var img = inputF.getFiles(/\.(png|jpg)$/i);
        if (img.length > 0) {
            if (sav.exists) {
                for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
                    var imgF = img[i];
                    var imgNm = imgF.displayName.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
                    if (imgNm[imgNm.length - 1] == 'X') {
                        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);
                        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);
                        var layers = activeDocument.layers;
                        if (layers) {
                            activeDocument.activeLayer = layers[0];
                            replaceeWithImage(imgF);
                            activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
                            activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
                            saveAllFrame(sav, imgNm.replace ('-X', alpha) + '.mp4');
                        } else {
                            activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
                            alert("No Smart Object Layer Found Inside The Smart Object Layer");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert("Images processed successfully!");
                $.sleep(4000);
                doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    alert("Select The Smart Object Layer Befor Running the script", "Smart Object Layer")
}
} else {
alert("Open a Template First", "Template")
}

function saveAllFrame(pth, nm) {
var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
desc2.putPath(stringIDToTypeID("directory"), new File(pth));
desc2.putString(charIDToTypeID('Nm  '), nm);
desc2.putString(stringIDToTypeID("ameFormatName"), "H.264");
desc2.putString(stringIDToTypeID("amePresetName"), "1_High Quality.epr");
desc2.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('Wdth'), 3500);
desc2.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('Hght'), 2304);
desc2.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("useDocumentFrameRate"), true);
desc2.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("pixelAspectRatio"), stringIDToTypeID("pixelAspectRatio"), charIDToTypeID('Dcmn'));
desc2.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("fieldOrder"), stringIDToTypeID("videoField"), stringIDToTypeID("preset"));
desc2.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("manage"), true);
desc2.putBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("allFrames"), true);
desc2.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("renderAlpha"), stringIDToTypeID("alphaRendering"), charIDToTypeID('None'));
desc2.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('Qlty'), 1);
desc1.putObject(charIDToTypeID('Usng'), stringIDToTypeID("videoExport"), desc2);
executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Expr'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
};

function replaceeWithImage(filePath) {
try {
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putPath(charIDToTypeID('null'), new File(filePath));
    executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerReplaceContents'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
};
```

Comment: Still scratching my head on why this could be happening. I don’t know why it’s not just working

Comment: savVideo code works fine for me. However, 'executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);' is down twice and I get the error 8800 "The Command 'Edit Contents' is not currently available.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out all the close commands? I've got a feeling it's trying to save a file that's just been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess - You're closing the jpg/png twice - which will close the source image

Also `executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'` down twice. I had to replace with `app.runMenuItem(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'));` as that wasn't working for me.

```
if (imgNm[imgNm.length - 1] == 'C')
{
    app.runMenuItem(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'));
    //executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);
    //executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO); //Why twice??
    var layers = activeDocument.layers;
    if (layers)
    {
        activeDocument.activeLayer = layers[0];
        replaceeWithImage(imgF);
        activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
        // activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES); // Why twice??
        savVideo(sav, imgNm + '-' + alpha + '.mp4');

    }
    else
    {
      activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
      alert("No Smart Object Layer Found Inside The Smart Object Layer");
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The PSD file that i'm working with has one smart object then placed within that smart object are two images placed on it (next to each other) which could be the reason for it being their twice. I don't know if I can upload the PSD files here. I tired that above but it doesn't work it still gives me an error

Comment: Can you walk me through the whole thing? - The script picks up a png/jpg from D:/START/ and processes one with a filename ending in C. As for the template and smart object that's guess work at the moment.  I don't think SO will allow you to upload a .psd but other (temp) file sites will.

Comment: I have updated my original post with a PSD file download link at the end of it. The Script Grabs a file with the ending name of -C as i am using it to create the mockups for the product which go on to be ending in -A and -B and so on. so really it just looking for a file with particular name to use.

Comment: I got it to work - but not by changing any code! I shrunk the Rotating Tumbler.psd down to 89% and it worked. At 90% it fell over with the 8800 error.

Comment: The straw may be causing problems. With Rotating Tumbler.psd at 89% the straw is a bit twitchy - [see for yourself](http://ghoulfool.co.uk/temp/imageC-F.mp4).  Whereas at a much smaller size it's [less so](http://ghoulfool.co.uk/temp/imageC-F.mp4)

Comment: I was able to change the Design layer to another image - but couldn't get the script to run (at a smaller template size)

Comment: so it didn't work at all for you?

Comment: Not at full scale, no.

Comment: You reckon I should just throw out the whole thing and start again and rebuild it?

Comment: No no. Can you swap out the export code for ScriptListener version? If not, call in bigger guns. The [elders may be able to help you.](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem/ct-p/ct-photoshop)  See also [this post.](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/help-with-render-mp4-animation-jsx-script/td-p/13921464)

Comment: I didn't write this script I had someone else make it and now they're stumped too, not sure how to do the Script Listener Version I can only just read javascript, I'll look into it.

Comment: [Scriptlistener](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html)

Comment: the guy that did the code and got back to me with it working! thanks again for replying and your help. gonna put the working code in question for anyone that comes across this